# How to insert data in other object in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have this object with data. This object `sites` is created from 50 values.

```
<div *ngFor="let site of sites; let i = index;">
  <div>
    <a class="title">
      {{article.title}}
    </a>
    <a>
      <p>{{article.content}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And now I created other object `banners` and I want to include value from banners in `sites` object, but the rule is like 2 items from first object, one item from second object, something like in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7xvk.png) .

How can we do this in Angular ?

Comment: Can you please provide more specific explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
<div *ngFor="let site of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]; let i = index;">

  <div>
    the site - {{site}} and the index is {{i}}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="i>0 && (1+i)%2 === 0">
    <a class="title">
      the article
      {{article.title}}
    </a>
    <a>
      <p>{{article.content}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```